# xtype vs type column in Sysobjects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone tell me why `Sysobjects` table have two columns `xtype` and `type`. Both are of data type `char(2)` and stores the object type.

Comment: And values for some ocject types differ for example Primary Key Constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `type` should be used as it is still in the new view. `xtype` is there for backward compatibility.

NOTE:

It appears that `sys.sysobjects` will be [removed in future versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) and you should use [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) instead.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005. Do you mean the column xtype was not there in SQL 2000.

Comment: @Nadeem - I had typo in my original answer and they were the wrong way around. `xtype` existed in SQL2K.  `type` will be used going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the definition of `sysobjects`

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sysobjects')) 
AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

Which Gives

```
CREATE VIEW sys.sysobjects AS
 SELECT  
 /*... Snip ...*/
 xtype = type collate database_default,
 /*... Snip ...*/
 type = convert(char(2), case type
  when 'UQ' then 'K' when 'PK' then 'K'
  else type collate database_default end),
 /*... Snip ...*/  
 FROM sys.sysschobjs
```

So it appears they only differ in whether `UQ` and `PK` or shown as `K` or not.